# Java Generics - Choosing the correct generic service

Tags: java, generics

Lets say we have a product of different types, the different types have different internal variables and does not share anything beside the fact they are all products.

```
public interface Product {}
public class ProductA implements Product {
    private String productAVariable;
    // getters
}
public class ProductB implements Product {
    private String productBVariable;
    // getters
}
```

To get the quote/price of a product we must call an external service:

```
public interface QuoteService<T extends Product> {
    ProductPrice getQuote(T product);
}
public class ProductAQuoteService implements QuoteService<ProductA> {
    @Override
    public ProductPrice getQuote(ProductA product) {
        return new ProductPrice(someExternalService.getQuote(product.getProductAVariable()));
    }
}
public class ProductBQuoteService implements QuoteService<ProductB> {
    @Override
    public ProductPrice getQuote(ProductB product) {
        return new ProductPrice(someOtherExternalService.getQuote(product.getProductBVariable()));
    }
}
```

So far so good. The last step is to iterate through a List of Products in our shoppingcart. Fetching the price/quote for each one. But how can we do that in a generic way? Currently i have some if-else instance of statements, but I feel there must be something more generic?

```
List<Product> productsInCart = Lists.asList(new ProductA(), new ProductB());
for (Product product : productsInCart) {
    if (product instanceof ProductA) {
        productAQuoteService.getQuote((ProductA) product);
    } else if (product instanceof ProductB) {
        productBQuoteService.getQuote((ProductB) product);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `getQuote()` not part of the `Product` interface?

Comment: @Turing85 Yes i did think about that for a while. But if it was, then the concrete product would have to have a reference to the concrete QuoteService. Which does not quite seem right. For every product added to the cart i would also have to add that reference...

Comment: I think you misunderstood. My question was: why do the `Product`-implementations not have a field `private ProductPrice quote` and a getter `public ProductPrice getQuote()`? Why do you need a service to fetch the quote?

Comment: No, you won't get that to work. Generics are for you, the programmer to write type safe code at *compile time*. Here you're looking for a way to get the right quote service for the right product at *runtime*. You're not actually getting any advantage from your interface or the generics (you can easily see it by removing them and noticing your latter code remains the same).

Comment: @Turing85 I need a service to fetch the quote because its an external soap service doing the actual quoting. So i would need some sort of reference to that service...

Comment: You can use a visitor to replace the if-/else chains. But as Kayaman wrote, I doubt there is any way to handle this "auto-magically", given the current constraints.